# Which is the mission 'Out of bullets'?

Tags: achievements, defense-grid-awakening

I would like to get the achievement **Out of Bullets** but I don't have the English version of the game. Can you please tell which is the number of mission called 'Out of Bullets'? Or post me a screenshot of that scenario?

Comment: Here's a hint for playing the actual levels: love the meteor tower. They're your best bet to punch through the shielded aliens / bulwarks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so this achievement is a little missleading. It's not a mission or campaign pack that's called "Out of Bullets"; instead, it refers to a specific challenge mode available to some story missions (5 in total)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I used this ticket to get me some cool shades for tf2

Comment: @Juan - use them when you play sniper, so you can wear shades with your shades, and look cool when you look cool.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the name of an actual mission. It's a mode for the normal original levels.
See:

Edit: I took [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBuTH.jpg) of the first mission that you can play in 'Out of Bullets' mode (which was added in a recent update).

Comment: Hello jaml, and welcome to gaming.stackexchange! It may interest you to know that stackexchange lets you embed images in your posts (via imgur, no less). There's no need to upload them on a separate site, the stackexchange engine will take care of all of that for you.

Answer (score 2):

Search for the Out Of Bullets game mode on five of the original levels. Select campaign "The Awakening" and mission "Ancient Research".